# nginx returns 403 forbidden error on file upload

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

I have a php website, in codeigniter, which allows users to upload files. Upload works fine for most of files. But for few files nginx throws **403 Forbidden** error. like

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
```

This is one of the sample .rb file that fails to upload

```
# Sample code from Programing Ruby, page 58
string = <<END_OF_STRING
    The body of the string
    is the input lines up to
    one ending with the same
    text that followed the '<<'
END_OF_STRING
```

If i remove `'<<'` from this file, upload works. Where is this filtration happening?

I have seen nginx error logs, nothing in there. I have seen codeigniter logs, nothing there.  Infact upload request doesn't reach my **Codeigniter controller**, so must be blocked before reaching there by nginx?

Here is upload code in Javascript

```
function upload(file, params) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("Filedata", file);
    $.each(params, function(key, value) {
       formData.append(key, value); 
    });

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var action = "/upload/file";

    xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e){
        // show progress with e.loaded, e.total
    };

    xhr.onerror = function(e) { 
        // handle error
    };

    xhr.open("POST", action, true);
    xhr.send(formData);
}
```

On server side, I have simple code for now.

```
if( !isset($_FILES['Filedata']) || !file_exists($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']) )
{
    die('File not submitted.');
} else { 
    // Save file code is here
}
```

Comment: Please see this link https://www.1and1.com/cloud-community/learn/web-server/nginx/solve-an-nginx-403-forbidden-error/

Comment: https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/403-forbidden-nginx/#

Comment: @AnandPandey I saw these links but this is not the issue in my case. Like I said most of the files upload fine without any error. This file also works fine if I remove '<<' characters. Seems like some content filtering is happening some where before reaching the php end.

Comment: What does your client side upload code look like? What does your server side upload handling code look like?

Comment: Related to mod security?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs like I said in question, all the files upload fine. Except the ones who has `'<` character in file contents. So its not a permission issue.

Comment: @Riz ah mb, skim-reading was my downfall here

Comment: @Alex didn't get what you wanted to say.

Comment: You need to explain more about your hosting environment. For example, which nginx modules are installed, are there AV tools installed, etc. It sounds like an AV filter is rejecting certain things because they fail a heuristic test.

Comment: enable nginx debug mode and detailed log and you should find out the problem

Comment: U cant see => https://nginxlibrary.com/403-forbidden-error/

Comment: @demenvil I have tried these already, doesn't apply in my case

Comment: Is port 80 open?

Comment: How your javascript call upload() ? What was the type of variable did you use for "file" paramater ?

Answer (score 0):

Try in your application/config/config.php
Change

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

by

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-><';
```

**But watch out for the security of your application**